# Adding ending zero's to a mysql table column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table named "Amount", which has amounts like 200, 300, 100 etc.
But, what I want is, that the amounts should be 200.00, 300.00,100.00. How do I write a query to update the column, so that it adds the ending zeroes? The column is float.

I tried with a regular update query, but it failed and I had to revert the changes (re-upload a backup sql file).

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What is the data type of `Amount`?  If it is not a numeric data type, then you have bigger problems than ending 0s.  If it is, switch it to a `decimal`, something like `decimal(10, 2)`.

Comment: Let's see your table definition and the query you tried to use. Is it possible you're trying to change the datatype from `INT` to `DECIMAL(11,2)` or some such thing?

Comment: @GordonLinoff

It is of Float.

Comment: @user3605847 . . . Phew.  Use `format()` or convert to a decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MySql Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/floating-point-types.html)

I think your best solution is an update your column

something like 
ALTER TABLE `Amount` MODIFY  `amount`  float(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;

Answer (score 0):

Number columns in MySQL (and probably most db engines) don't actually save numbers like that, but binary. If you're interested, it's probably something like [IEEE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

There is a data type that does save numbers literally: `DECIMAL`. If you save `5.2` into a `DECIMAL(2, 4)`, it saves the number as `5.2000`. Decimals are saved as strings and only 'converted' into a number when it's saved into the db.

You could try altering the column into a `DECIMAL(n, 2)`, but depending on how smart MySQL is, that doesn't update the values correctly:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
  MODIFY your_column DECIMAL(5, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 -- etc
```

Comment: for the most part I agree but why not just keep the float value type?  See my answer.

Comment: It was already a `FLOAT`.... And a `FLOAT` doesn't keep trailing 0-decimals. `DECIMAL` does.

Comment: Rudi I thought that too but looking at the docs and trying it on my own , float does allow for precision so float(7,2) would work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
update Amount set floati = concat(floati,'.00');
```

**Example:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa240/1

Comment: How do I make something that automatically checks all the values entered in the database should have the zeroes ? (If the value doesn't have a decimal)

Comment: It didn't work as well.
Says :- 0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0005 sec)

Comment: Send the table schema